# Most idiomatic way to prepend an element to a List ifNotEmpty() in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, idioms

I want to prepend a `List<Thing>` with an element, but only if the list is not empty.

I was thinking about a combination of `takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }`, `orEmpty()`, and `flatMap`.

What's the most idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: No need for fancy stuff: `if (list.isEmpty()) list else listOf(e) + list`. If you don't like `list` duplication, create a function with this body.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
val myEmptyList = listOf<String>()
val myNotEmptyList = listOf<String>("is", "the", "worst")

listOf("first").takeIf { myEmptyList.isNotEmpty() }.orEmpty() + myEmptyList
listOf("first").takeIf { myNotEmptyList.isNotEmpty() }.orEmpty() + myNotEmptyList
```

The output:

```
[]
[first, is, the, worst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code that is pretty idiomatic IMHO:

```
infix fun <T> Collection<T>?.prependIfNotEmpty(other: Collection<T>): Collection<T>? =
        if (this?.isNotEmpty() == true)
            other + this
        else
            this

// or for non nullable lists your approach
infix fun <T> Collection<T>.prependIfNotEmptyNonNull(other: Collection<T>): Collection<T> = other.takeIf { isNotEmpty() }.orEmpty() + this
```

usage

```
listOf(1, 2, 3) prependIfNotEmpty listOf(-1, 0) // [-1,0,1,2,3]

listOf("two", "three", "four").prependIfNotEmpty(listOf("zero", "one")) // ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"]

val list: List<Float>? = null

list prependIfNotEmpty listOf(3.5, 5.6) // null

//for prependIfNotEmptyNonNull the same usage
```

Maybe there is a more idiomatic way but I still yet to figure it out.

Hope it helps.